# Does UML merge node doesn't exit until all flows have arrived at the merge node?

Tags: uml, uml-decision-node, uml-merge-node

I'm beginner in `UML` and try understand it. Now I read [`UML Demystified`](http://doi.contentdirections.com/mr/mgh.jsp?doi=10.1036/007226182X). There is this sentence:

> A merge node doesn't exit until all flows have arrived at the merge
>   node.

But there is a figure titled as `Figure 15.12 Activity node example (where the arrowed lines are the only non-activity node symbols)` in [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/):

[image]

Now I think if above sentence is true, above diagram says `Activity` will be block by `merge` node; because *arriving all flows* is impossible; because an order only can be rejected or accepted.

Now I want to know is quoted sentence is incorrect or am I misunderstanding somethings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the UML 2.5 specs:

> **15.7.21 MergeNode [Class]**
>
> A merge node is a control node that brings together multiple alternate flows. It is not used to synchronize concurrent flows but to accept one among several alternate flows.

So it accepts a single token at any time and passes it to its outgoing flows. Generally, what book authors write is their interpretation - which might be wrong. In any case you need to stick to what the UML spec says.